# How can I use dd to back up the whole disk from inside a linux-vserver guest?

Tags: linux, backup, dd, guest

I have a Linux-vserver guest I want to dump the whole disk of. I have no access to the host.

I tried:

```
dd if=/dev/hdv1 | gzip -c | ssh user@remote.host.net 'dd of=/path/to/file.img' bs=2048
```

but the result was:

```
dd: opening `/dev/hdv1': No such file or directory
```

Running df inside the linux-vserver guest gives this result:

```
root@vs8904:~# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/hdv1              1511856   1409764     25292  99% /
root@vs8904:~#
```

But:

```
root@vs8904:~# ls -al /dev/hd*
ls: cannot access /dev/hd*: No such file or directory
root@vs8904:~#
```

Is there any tool which will allow me this?

I can not have any access to the host machine hosting this linux-vserver.

Answer (score 1):

Is is a [Linux-VServer](http://linux-vserver.org/Welcome_to_Linux-VServer.org) guest? If so it's only a "advanced" chroot and your guest only have a virtual-disk that is actually a directory on the host. So dd will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do a **full backup** of a Linux-VServer, you need to use *rsync* and not `dd`. You should be able to find the relevant documentation on their website.